# AS3 child issue with if statements

Tags: actionscript-3

Alright, can someone explain what is wrong with my code below, there is no errors, but it's not doing what I want it to do. I need it to display a movieclip on the screen when a variable called "randint", which is generated by random, is greater than or equal to 0.5. If it's not then it doesn't get displayed. Code:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, char_coll);
function char_coll(ev : Event) : void
{
    if(currentFrame==2)
    {
        if (randint >= 0.5){
            var w1:woman1 = new woman1();
            randint = Math.random();
            if(w1.hitTestObject(stand)){
                w1.gotoAndPlay(1);
                cash1 = cash1 + 1;
        }
        }

    }
};
```

Comment: It's worth noting that 'randint' is a misnomer here as Math.random returns a float between 0 & 1.

Answer (score 0):

`randint` is set inside the if statement. This means that `randint` always is undefiend, because it has to be `>= 0.5` to be set to any value (kind of a catch 22).

This code should work:

```
addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, char_coll);
function char_coll(ev : Event) : void
{
    if(currentFrame==2)
    {
        var randint:Number = Math.random();
        if (randint >= 0.5){
            var w1:woman1 = new woman1();
            stage.addChild(w1);
            if(w1.hitTestObject(stand)){
                w1.gotoAndPlay(1);
                cash1 = cash1 + 1;
            }
        }

    }
};
```

Then of course you have to add `w1` to the stage using `addChild()` as you can se below var `w1:woman1 = new woman1();`

hope it helps!

Comment: Well now my hitobject if statement isn't working. Any ideas on why?

Comment: Sorry, not without knowing where you get "stand" from? Is it another sprite?

Comment: Yes, stand is another instance name for a movieclip on scene.

Comment: Are they in the same position then? Are the sprites overlapping? When you simply call addChild() the clip is placed att position 0x0 on the parent object. Move it to a position that will make w1 overlap stand (w1.x = ?? w1.y = ??), does hittest still not fire? It could be helpfull with some more code ... Feels like I'm guessing in the dark here

Comment: It seems like hittest has changed from AS2 to AS3. It is now called hitTestObject and hitTextPoint or something ... I found a tutorial here: http://www.flashperfection.com/tutorials/Simple-hit-test-in-Actionscript-3-12133.html It might be a start

Comment: I'm using the correct form of hittestobject in my code. It's not that. It must be something else.